# Strange system.void return exception generated when running a mapped stored procedure method in LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure (pseudocode below) that goes as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
AS
BEGIN

 CREATE DummyTable

 INSERT INTO DummyTable
 SELECT xxx

 INSERT INTO DummyTable
 SELECT yyy

 IF EXISTS FinalTable DROP FinalTable

 EXEC sp_RENAME 'DummyTable', 'FinalTable'

END
GO
```

Note that there is no return type/value for this stored proc. I have this stored proc mapped in my LINQ-TO-SQL designer (ASP.NET MVC2 application). However, when I call the method as follows:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
 context.MyProc();
}
```

However, in my logs, I have found that this exception is being generated when this method is run:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   'System.Void' is not a valid return
>   type for a mapped stored procedure
>   method.  at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.TranslateStoredProcedureCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mce, MetaFunction function)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMappedFunctionCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mc)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mc)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression
>   node)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression
>   node)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression
>   query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
>   at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)  at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object
>   instance, MethodInfo methodInfo,
>   Object[] parameters)

Can anyone help me identify why this exception is being generated?

Thanks,
A.

UPDATED: The auto generated code in the L2S designer file is:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.MyProc")]
public void MyProc()
{
 this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
}
```

Comment: It appears that messages returned by SQL Server after inserting confuse linq. The answer suggested by Simon actually solves the problem (even though it looks like it's something completely unrelated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys just to let you know I set `nocount on` and this sorted the problem!

I had to re-add my sp in designer mode.

Comment: Oddly enough, this actually works. I guess linq goes crazy if the procedure outputs any messages. After I added `SET nocount on;` at the top of the SP, I had to re-add it to the dbml and even set the return type to int, however after doing that, the return type said `(none)` and everything worked without exception (sorry for the pun).

Answer (score 3):

What did the generated linq-to-sql code look like?  Perhaps you manually changed it to return void?

Creating a stored proc that doesn't give output like so -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DropMe')
    DROP TABLE DropMe
END
GO
```

should generate the following code when adding it to the l2s design surface -

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.MyProc")]
        public int MyProc()
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

If yours is returning void instead, that will cause it to throw that exception.

So if i change the above to this -

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.MyProc")]
    public void MyProc()
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
        return;
    }
```

It will throw this when invoked -

> Line 17:      public void MyProc() Line
>   18:       { Line 19:          IExecuteResult
>   result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
>   ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
>   Line 20:          return;//
>   ((int)(result.ReturnValue)); Line 21:
>         }
>
> Source File: C:\Build\blah.cs    Line:
>   19
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException:
>   'System.Void' is not a valid return
>   type for a mapped stored procedure
>   method.]
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.TranslateStoredProcedureCall(MethodCallExpression
>   mce, MetaFunction function) +904265

Comment: Unfortunately the designer generated code does not have the return keyword. I've updated the original post with auto-generated code.

Comment: Can you change the return type in the dbml file with the designer?

Comment: At the moment, the designer shows the 'Return Type' field to be empty (which was the default). I suppose that I could try changing it to Int and then implementing the code you have above to return the IExecuteResult but it would seem strange that I have to manually go in and hack about with the designer file. Would I need to return a dummy integer in my Stored Proc to appease the IExecuteResult result?

Comment: I tried changing the return type in the designer to 'object' (I also tried 'int' too) and unfortunately that didn't work either (I get a different type of exception about not being able to translate the SQL). In the end I have decided just to take the easy route out and remove the mapped stored procedure from the L2S design surface and hard-code in a call to the stored procedure as: context.ExecuteCommand("exec dbo.[MyProc]");

Comment: Thanks @Frank, this worked for me.  Didn't realize `int` is the default when you don't explicitly return something from the SP.