# Stored Procedure does not and should not return anything results in error

Tags: linq, stored-procedures

I have a stored Procedure that we are using to simply do an insert of a new record into various tables.  This Stored Procedure is setup to not return anything only to execute.  When I pull it into my DBML it sets it up as a "Void" which I think is correct.  Here is the auto generated code from the DMBL.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.sp_PTS_Action_Insert_Comment")]
        public void sp_PTS_Action_Insert_Comment([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Form_Name", DbType="VarChar(20)")] string form_Name, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Form_Number", DbType="VarChar(25)")] string form_Number, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="UID", DbType="VarChar(15)")] string uID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Cmt", DbType="VarChar(200)")] string cmt)
        {
            this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), form_Name, form_Number, uID, cmt);
        }
    }
```

I call this SP as follows:

```
_context.sp_PTS_Action_Insert_Comment(formInformation["formType"], formInformation["formNumber"], userId, comment);
```

When this code executes it throws an error saying

> "System Void not a valid return type
>   for a mapped Stored Procedure"

My question is can you use linq to Stored Procedure with SP's that purposely do not return anything?  And if so what am I doing wrong in this example?

Comment: Related post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193583/strange-system-void-return-exception-generated-when-running-a-mapped-stored-proce

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of why, when putting a procedure that doesn't return anything, that Linq builds the above void function, because it DOES throw the 'not a valid return type' error.

To fix this I've added a return to the procedure using SCOPE_IDENTITY() as my return so then I can use it in my code also.

Hope that helps.